# Layout for label and button programmatically

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, springlayout

I am trying to create a SpringLayout in Java, this is the code I have (got it from Oracle Java docs)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SpringForm {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        String[] labels = {"Side1: ", "Side2: ", "Side3: "};
        int numPairs = labels.length;
        //Create and populate the panel.
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
        javax.swing.JButton calculate_btn;
        calculate_btn = new javax.swing.JButton();             

        for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
            JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i], JLabel.TRAILING);
            p.add(l);
            JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
            l.setLabelFor(textField);
            p.add(textField);
        }
        calculate_btn.setText("Calculate");
        p.add(calculate_btn);
        //Lay out the panel.
        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(p,
            numPairs, 2, //rows, cols
            6, 6,        //initX, initY
            6, 6);       //xPad, yPad     
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
        //Set up the content pane.
        p.setOpaque(true);  //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(p);     
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With the above code I am getting this

[image]

But in actual I am looking to get this

[image]

I DONOT MIND ANY OTHER LAYOUT! it's just that the oracle help shows that springlayout really close to my need
I am trying to do is get the layout as below picture, I am not sure what is the layout used in the below, and also in my attempt I am using SpringLayout I noticed that the controls change their sizes automatically when we extend the window size I want to disable this but it kind of doesn't make sense as SpringLayout clearly means what it is doing, adjusting the controls, when we adjust the window

Comment: have been trying the whole day, to get the layout programatically, I dont mind any layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Java trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) of `SpringLayout` (pretty much the first line, actually):

> The `SpringLayout` class was added in JDK version 1.4 to support layout in GUI builders. `SpringLayout` is a very flexible layout manager that can emulate many of the features of other layout managers. `SpringLayout` is, however, very low-level and as such **you really should only use it with a GUI builder, rather than attempting to code a spring layout manager by hand**. (Emphasis added.)

I've been programming professionally in Java for years now and even I won't program `SpringLayout` by hand. My recommendation is to use the [MigLayout library](http://www.miglayout.com/) instead. Their API is much simpler for layout-by-hand code and can produce very near-native layouts. I've been using it for a long time now, and I prefer it over anything else I've tried. It's especially nice when used in conjunction with Java's [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) due to the way space-filling works. I highly recommend it.

---

First things first:

1. MigLayout is cell-based, but also supports splitting and spanning cells. If you've ever worked with HTML or Excel, you should know what that means. It's pretty self-explanatory.
2. MigLayout's default method of input is strings, and they're the simplest to understand, but they also have a very good API for creating layouts as well.
3. MigLayout supports far more than I'll ever be able to cover in an SO question, so follow the link above and check out the quick start guide and cheat sheet. They're by far the best resource for what you can put in your constraints.

Here is an example using `MigLayout` to produce a similar layout to the example image you posted:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing MigLayout");
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new MigLayout("fillx"));

    // Row 1
    JLabel areaLabel = new JLabel("Area of Triangle");
    areaLabel.setFont(areaLabel.getFont().deriveFont(16.0f));
    areaLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(areaLabel, "spanx, growx, wrap");
    // wrap indicates a new row

    // Row 2
    JLabel side1Label = new JLabel("Side 1:");
    contentPane.add(side1Label, "alignx trailing");
    JTextField side1Field = new JTextField();
    side1Field.setColumns(6);
    contentPane.add(side1Field, "alignx leading, wrap");

    // Row 3
    JLabel side2Label = new JLabel("Side 2:");
    contentPane.add(side2Label, "alignx trailing");
    JTextField side2Field = new JTextField();
    side2Field.setColumns(6);
    contentPane.add(side2Field, "alignx leading, wrap");

    // Row 4
    JLabel side3Label = new JLabel("Side 3:");
    contentPane.add(side3Label, "alignx trailing");
    JTextField side3Field = new JTextField();
    side3Field.setColumns(6);
    contentPane.add(side3Field, "alignx leading, wrap");

    // Row 5
    JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate Area");
    contentPane.add(calculateButton, "spanx, growx");

    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    // Resizes automatically
    frame.pack();
    // Centers automatically
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // Exit when the frame is closed
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

And its output:

[image: MigLayout Example]

This is without all the logic, of course, but it still shows MigLayout's power. When you start getting into more complex applications and want components to expand and contract with the window, MigLayout does very well. If you've ever used `GridBadLayout`, you'll notice that `MigLayout` is just a suped up version of it.

For references about what all the individual pieces of this are, just look at the cheat sheet. There's an explanation for every piece I used. Specifically, anything declared in the `MigLayout` constructor (here, `"fillx"`) is a layout constraint, and anything declared in the `add` methods (such as `"spanx"` and `"wrap"`) are component constraints. There's more you can do with practice and experimentation to get just the right combination that creates an excellent GUI.

That being said, there's always other, simpler layout managers like `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout`. For simple applications like yours, those layout managers are perfectly fine. When you start getting into the more intensive applications, I recommend breaking into MigLayout. For reading up on those, I recommend the Java trails. There's a [visual guide to layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) on there as well, and you can use that as a jumping-off point. I recommend sticking with these for layout-by-hand:

- `BorderLayout`
- `BoxLayout`
- `CardLayout`
- `FlowLayout`
- `GridBagLayout`
- `GridLayout`

Comment: hey tks man, I have given it a go in the morning but since I am just starting out in Java found it a bit difficult to understand but i am sure it is easy. But you are welcome to prove me otherwise. :) tks

Comment: Sure, I'll add some examples for MigLayout.

Comment: I actually dont mind any layout for now to get the simple layout as my second picture its just that the I am good at see and learn.. tks so much brian

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you have any more questions, I'll be happy to answer them... In the morning.

Comment: sure brian, I will be going for my lecture later tonight , after that I will implement this or as you suggested I will use the traditional layouts and try that...really appreciate your help! :) goodnight mate!

Comment: Tks Brian, this will also help me understanding what is the bigdeal about MIGlayout!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use the spring layout, but outside of an GUI editor I found it very confusing.
If you can, I'll recommand you to switch to another manager.

- The [JGoodies' FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/) is very well known and it is supported by many GUI builders. The syntax can be hard to catch at first, but once you get it, building nice forms is really easy
- [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is said to be a very good one too

Comment: I actually dont mind any layout for now to get the simple layout as my second picture its just that the I am good at see and learn

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand your comment... If you don't want to use any out of the box layouts, please try to use something simpler than the spring layout (like a grid layout, or a combination of other simpler layouts. The SpringLayout is not meant to be used manually...

Comment: Oh I was just asking for your help if you know any other simpler method to do this, programatically I meant, sorry for not being clear earlier